# Condition in Scala Map method

Tags: python, arrays, scala, dictionary

In Python, I can easily create a new list by condition

```py
list_1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
new_list = [e for e in list_1 if e>3]
# result [4,5]
```

But not the same story for Scala. I tried using map map method

```scala
var array_1 = Array(1,2,3,4,5)
var new_array = array_1.map(e => if(e>3) e)
// result: [undefined, undefined, undefined, 4, 5]
```

Is there any magic I dont know here?
Thankful for helping me

Comment: array_1.filter(_ > 3)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`filter`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Array.html#filter(p:A=%3EBoolean):Array[A]) like so

```
var new_array = array_1.filter(e => e > 3)
```

which outputs

```
new_array: Array[Int] = Array(4, 5)
```

Answer (score 3):

The solution which @Mario suggested is the preferred way to achieve this in scala.

Anyway, you can also achieve this by using a for comprehension which is similar to the way it's done in python:

```
for {e <- array_1; if e > 3} yield e
```

This code get desugared to a `filter` method invocation.

Answer (score 1):

`map` is just to apply a method to every element.

`filter` is to filter every element.

You can combine them doing a single `collect` with a [`Partial Function`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.8/scala/PartialFunction.html)

```
Seq(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).collect{
  case e if 3 < e => 2*e
}
```